# How to segue programmatically from 1VC to 2VC (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 view controllers (**VC1** & **VC2**). Both of them are made **programmatically** without InterfaceBuilder. I'm trying to **segue from VC1 to VC2** through code. I know there are methods like:

- performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)
- prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

But I don't have VC2 identifier and I don't have Storyboard. So how to segue through code? Just 5 days with Swift. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segues are specific to Storyboards (hence the class name – UIStoryboardSegue). If you want to perform a transition from VC1 to VC2 programmatically you have two options:

1. Present VC2 modally in VC1:

   ```
   let vc2 = VC2()
   self.present(vc2, animated: true)

   // to return from VC2 to VC1 call this somewhere in VC2
   self.dismiss(animated: true)
   ```
2. Wrap VC1 in a UINavigationController and then push VC2 to it when needed:

   ```
   let vc2 = VC2()
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)

   // to return from VC2 to VC1 call this somewhere in VC2
   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Segues are a storyboard thing. You can't use segues without storyboards.

The simple answer to your question is that you can't do that. If you don't use storyboards, you can't use `UIStoryboardSegue`s. That's why they're called storyboard segues. Segues are provided by Storyboards.

Stop fighting the tools and start using Storyboards. (I would not hire somebody who said "I don't use Storyboards. I write all my interfaces in code" any more than I would hire somebody who eschews high level languages and does everything in assembly language. Yes it's possible, but why would you do that?)

Comment: Storyboards are 1) a nightmare when you need to merge changes from several commits 2) the source of a lot of errors due to implicitly unwrapped optionals for IBOutlets.

Comment: Thank you for advise. I'm not familiar with Xcode yet, but for the first look InterfaceBuilder has so much bugs (especially constraints). Maybe it's only my issue.

Comment: The fact is that you **can't** use segues except from a Storyboard. The class is named UI**Storyboard**Segue, after all.